# Group by dynamic number of columns in java list of map

Tags: java, group-by, java-stream

I have the following `aList` object:

```
    List<Map<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,String> mapOne= new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> mapTwo= new HashMap<>();
    mapOne.put("Name","John");
    mapOne.put("Age","30");
    mapOne.put("City","Kolkata");
    mapTwo.put("Name","Jack");
    mapTwo.put("Age","31");
    mapTwo.put("City","Kolkata");
    aList.add(mapOne);
    aList.add(mapTwo);
```

My requirement is to now return a list of results based on **dynamic** number of order by clause. So I wrote the following code to order by `City`

```
        Map<String, List<Collection<String>>> city = aList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> map.get("City")
                    , Collectors.mapping(Map::values, Collectors.toList())));
    System.out.println(city);
```

But as you notice, here I am able to group by only `city` but the user should have the choice to group by with other attributes like `Name`, `Age` and so on. So how can I return the result when I do not know which and how many attributes the user is going to choose to group by?

Comment: @user7, yeah I understand that but the problem is it may be only `city` or a combination of `city` and `name` and so on.....

Comment: How can that be a combination? In that case do you want to return two `Map<String, List<Collection<String>>>`?

Comment: @user7 I only need the map, I am going to print the value in the frontend for the user. The key can be the combination of the user choice so of course it should change to `Map<List,List<Collection<String>>>`

Comment: Can you show an example for how the result will look like for multiple criteria?

Comment: @user7 So right now it is printing like `{Kolkata=[[Kolkata, 30, John], [Kolkata, 31, Jack]]}` I am imaginig for multiple group by e.g. with city and age, it should look like `{[Kolkata,30]=[[Kolkata, 30, John]]}

{[Kolkata,31]=[[Kolkata, 31, Jack]]}`
So I am sorry probably the result should be like List<Map<List<String>,List<String>>>`

Comment: representing the `Map` as an object `@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Person {
    String name;
    int age; // you can choose as 'String' as well
    String city;
}` might just be better.

Comment: @Naman I understand, but this is the structure in which I am getting the data from another application so I have on control over that.

Comment: @Mistu4u deserialising and mapping to object types is quite a known thing for such use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to return a `Map<List<String>, List<Collection<String>>>` when there are more then one criteria.

You can make the `groupingBy` *classifier* to return a map with the desired field's values and then group by that list.

```
Map<List<String>, List<Collection<String>>> city = aList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> List.of(map.get("City"), map.get("Age")),
                Collectors.mapping(Map::values, Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println(city);
```

This prints

```
{[Kolkata, 30]=[[Kolkata, 30, John]], [Kolkata, 31]=[[Kolkata, 31, Jack]]}
```

Replace `List.of(..)` with `Arrays.asList(..)` if you are using Java < 9.

To make this dynamic, you can move the logic to build the classifier function to a method and call it for each map.

```
private static List<String> buildClassificationFunction(Map<String,String> map, List<String> fields) {
    return fields.stream()
            .map(map::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

List<String> fields = List.of("City", "Age"); //This will be constructed as per user's wish

Map<List<String>, List<Collection<String>>> city = aList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> 
                    buildClassificationFunction(map, fields), //Call the function to build the list
                Collectors.mapping(Map::values, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: That buildClassificationFunction is what I was going to ask but you added it, perfect answer!